# Send email to multiple users within an account when criteria is met in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails application what I want to send my users notifications when certain criteria are met.  I can do this through a rake task.  Currently I'm able to select the records that meet the criteria and email them to a specific address.  The issue is that it sends ALL the records for all the accounts.  Here's what I have in the rake task:

```
task :send_reminds => :environment do
    equipment = Equipment.where("calibration_date <= ?", Date.today)
    EquipmentMailer.out_of_calibration(equipment).deliver
end
```

Here is the code for my EquipmentMailer:

```
class EquipmentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "mark.odonnell@azzurgroup.com"

  def out_of_calibration(equipment)
    @equipment = Equipment.where("calibration_date <= ?", Date.today)
    mail(:to => "markaodonnell@gmail.com", :subject => "Equipment is out of calibration")
  end
end
```

Here is the code for my HTML email (which works as expected):

```
The following Equipment is Due:
<br></br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Equipment Name</th>
    <th>   </th>
    <th>Calibration Due Date</th>
  </tr>
  <% @equipment.each do |equipment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= equipment.equipment_id %></td>
    <td>  </td>
    <td><%= equipment.calibration_date %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

As you can see I'm sending the email directly to myself and receive the equipment list that meets the criteria.  But that is unacceptable of course.  I want the email to go to all the users within an account that has equipment that is out of calibration.  Here are my models:

Equipment.rb

```
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tenant(:account)

  validates :equipment_id, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true

  validates_uniqueness_to_tenant :serial_number

  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true

  has_paper_trail


def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
  search(query)
    else
        scoped
    end
end
```

User.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tenant(:account)
  validates_uniqueness_to_tenant :email

   attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :title, :company,
                                    :phone, :mobile,     :admin
  has_secure_password
  before_save :create_remember_token

  belongs_to :account

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

#  has_paper_trail

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

Account.rb

```
    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subdomain, :email
  VALID_SUBDOMAIN_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+(-[a-z\d])+(-[a-z\d])/i
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :subdomain, :presence => true, 
            :uniqueness => true
  validates :email, :presence => true,
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  validates_presence_of :plan_id  

  belongs_to :plan

  has_many  :users
  has_many  :equipment, :through => :users

  before_save { |account| account.subdomain = account.subdomain.downcase }
end
```

I have tried something like this for the mail(:to => user.email) instead of a direct address while limiting the equipment list to be specific to an account and it's users.

```
@equipment = Equipment.where("calibration_date <= ?", Date.today)  
  @equipment.each do |equipment|
    equipment.accounts.each do |account|
      accounts.users.each do |user|
        user.email.each do |email|
          mail(:to => email, :subject => "Equipment is out of calibration"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The rake task will run without errors but I get no emails.  Thoughts?  BTW, I'm only about 1 month into rails so if I'm missing something extremely elementary you'll have to forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the problem lives in this code

```
def out_of_calibration(equipment)
    @equipment = Equipment.where("calibration_date <= ?", Date.today)
    mail(:to => "markaodonnell@gmail.com", :subject => "Equipment is out of calibration")
  end
```

You are not using the argument that is passed in to that method AT ALL.

Comment: Correct.  I need to replace "markaodonnell@gmail.com" with something like "user.email" but I need to define that email by saying that when equipment_date <= Date.today, send it to all the users in the account where equipment_date <= Date.today.

Answer (score 0):

Your associations don't look right, it looks like accounts should have_many equipments and accounts should have_many users.  User should belong_to account and equipment should belong_to account.  Can equipments belong to multiple accounts?  Doesn't make sense.  I would suggest the following:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users
 has_many :equipments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :equipments, :through => :account
end

@equipment = Equipment.where("calibration_date <= ?", Date.today)  
  @equipment.each do |equipment|
    equipment.users.each do |user|
      mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Equipment is out of calibration"
  end
end
```